# GridGain Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobContext

Tags: java, hadoop, gridgain

I have configured gridgain-hadoop-os-6.6.2.zip, and followed steps as mentioned in `docs/hadoop_readme.pdf` . started gridgain using bin/ggstart.sh command, now am running a simple wordcount code in gridgain with hadoop-2.2.0. using command

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*-mapreduce-examples-*.jar wordcount /input /output
```

**Steps I tried:**

**Step 1:**
Extracted hadoop-2.2.0 and gridgain-hadoop-os-6.6.2.zip file in usr/local folder and changed name for gridgain folder as "gridgain".

**Step 2:**
 Set the path for export GRIDGAIN_HOME=/usr/local/gridgain.. and path for hadoop-2.2.0 with JAVA_HOME as

```
    # Set Hadoop-related environment variables
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
export YARN_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hadoop
export GRIDGAIN_HADOOP_CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/*'
```

**Step 3:**

now i run command as `bin/setup-hadoop.sh` ... answer Y to every prompt.

**Step 4:**

started gridgain using command

bin/ggstart.sh

**Step 5:**

now i created dir and uploaded file using :

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /input

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $HADOOP_HOME/README.txt /input/WORD_COUNT_ME.
txt
```

**Step 6:**

Running this command gives me error:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*-mapreduce-examples-*.
jar wordcount /input /output
```

Getting following error:

```
15/02/22 12:49:13 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
15/02/22 12:49:13 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_091ebfbd-2993-475f-a506-28280dbbf891_0002
15/02/22 12:49:13 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_091ebfbd-2993-475f-a506-28280dbbf891_0002
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gridgain.client.hadoop.GridHadoopClientProtocol.processStatus(GridHadoopClientProtocol.java:329)
    at org.gridgain.client.hadoop.GridHadoopClientProtocol.submitJob(GridHadoopClientProtocol.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

and gridgain console error as:

```
sLdrId=a0b8610bb41-091ebfbd-2993-475f-a506-28280dbbf891, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=java.lang.String, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=0]], taskClsName=o.g.g.kernal.processors.hadoop.proto.GridHadoopProtocolSubmitJobTask, sesId=e129610bb41-091ebfbd-2993-475f-a506-28280dbbf891, startTime=1424589553332, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=091ebfbd-2993-475f-a506-28280dbbf891, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1bdcbb2, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, subjId=091ebfbd-2993-475f-a506-28280dbbf891], jobId=f129610bb41-091ebfbd-2993-475f-a506-28280dbbf891]]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1723)
    at org.gridgain.grid.hadoop.GridHadoopDefaultJobInfo.createJob(GridHadoopDefaultJobInfo.java:107)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.hadoop.jobtracker.GridHadoopJobTracker.job(GridHadoopJobTracker.java:959)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.hadoop.jobtracker.GridHadoopJobTracker.submit(GridHadoopJobTracker.java:222)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.hadoop.GridHadoopProcessor.submit(GridHadoopProcessor.java:188)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.hadoop.GridHadoopImpl.submit(GridHadoopImpl.java:73)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.hadoop.proto.GridHadoopProtocolSubmitJobTask.run(GridHadoopProtocolSubmitJobTask.java:54)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.hadoop.proto.GridHadoopProtocolSubmitJobTask.run(GridHadoopProtocolSubmitJobTask.java:37)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.hadoop.proto.GridHadoopProtocolTaskAdapter$Job.execute(GridHadoopProtocolTaskAdapter.java:95)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:484)
    at org.gridgain.grid.util.GridUtils.wrapThreadLoader(GridUtils.java:6136)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:478)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:429)
    at org.gridgain.grid.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.hadoop.GridHadoopClassLoader.loadClass(GridHadoopClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.hadoop.GridHadoopClassLoader.loadClassExplicitly(GridHadoopClassLoader.java:196)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.hadoop.GridHadoopClassLoader.loadClass(GridHadoopClassLoader.java:106)
    ... 21 more
^[[B
```

Help here....

**Edited Here** :

```
raj@ubuntu:~$ hadoop classpath
/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
raj@ubuntu:~$ jps
3529 GridCommandLineStartup
3646 Jps
raj@ubuntu:~$ echo $GRIDGAIN_HOME
/usr/local/gridgain
raj@ubuntu:~$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
raj@ubuntu:~$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.2.0
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1529768
Compiled by hortonmu on 2013-10-07T06:28Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 79e53ce7994d1628b240f09af91e1af4
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
raj@ubuntu:~$ cd /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce
raj@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce$ ls
hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar     hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.2.0.jar          hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0-tests.jar  lib
hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar  hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.2.0.jar  hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar          lib-examples
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar    hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar   hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar                sources
raj@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce$
```

Comment: Question is edited ...

Comment: Steps has been edited..

Comment: Edited Suggested Paths..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I configured exactly the versions you mentioned (gridgain-hadoop-os-6.6.2.zip + hadoop-2.2.0) -- the "wordcount" sample works fine.

---

[UPD after question's author log analysis:]

Raju, thanks for the detailed logs. 
The cause of the problem are incorrectly set env variables

```
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
```

You explicitly set all these variables to ${HADOOP_HOME} value, what is *wrong*. This causes GG to compose incorrect hadoop classpath, as seen from the below GG Node log:

```
+++ HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
+++ [[ -z /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0 ]]
+++ '[' -z /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0 ']'
+++ HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
+++ HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
+++ HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
+++ GRIDGAIN_HADOOP_CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/*'
```

So, to fix the issue please *don't* set unnecessary env variables. JAVA_HOME  and HADOOP_HOME is quite enough, nothing else is needed.

Comment: hi Ivan Veselovsky, Thanks for reply. i have edited question. i thought it may be because of my machine , but i tried it in other three machines , it is not working there too,...

Comment: Jar file hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar, is there in path <HADOOP_HOME>/share/hadoop/mapreduce/...

Comment: Raju, the following may help to investigate: 
cd gridgain-hadoop-os-6.6.2/bin/
edit the following files and add "-x" after "/bin/bash":
./ggstart.sh:1:#!/bin/bash -x
./include/setenv.sh:1:#!/bin/bash -x
./include/hadoop-classpath.sh:1:#!/bin/bash -x
after that start the GG node and see the log: there should be clear how the script composes the GG classpath, and if the client-core-XXX.jar added into there.

Comment: Thanks , anyway couldnt get it, after adding -x, in as mentioned files...  Can you provide me the link from where you have downloaded , hadoop-2.2.0 and gridgain accelerator.. may be i am missing something here.... i tried it lot.... but couldnt succeed...

Comment: Hi, Raju, 
Hadoop: https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.2.0/hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz
GG: http://www.gridgain.com/media/gridgain-hadoop-os-6.6.2.zip 
Can you please provide detailed step-by-step list of actions you're performing to set this up from scratch?
Also, can you send full logs obtained with "-x" in scripts to my email iveselovskiy@gridgain.com .

Comment: Raju, thanks for detaild logs. 
The cause of the problem is incorrectly set env variables
+++ HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
+++ [[ -z /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0 ]]
+++ '[' -z /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0 ']'
+++ HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
+++ HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
+++ HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0
+++ GRIDGAIN_HADOOP_CLASSPATH='/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/*'
{code}

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help... but it is showing same error... may i know what does "+++" symbol means for in .bashrc file., i copied and pasted it but it didnt work and shows symbol not found when starting terminal.... even i replaced "+++" with export... the same error (Null Pointer Exception) is showing when running simple word count...

Answer (score 0):

many thnaks to Ivan, thanks for your help and support, the solution you gave was good to get me out of the problem.

The issue was not to set other hadoop related environment variables. this is enough to set.

```
JAVA_HOME , HADOOP_HOME and GRIDGAIN_HOME
```